# passing Sessions user ID across pages

Tags: php, session

I need to pass the sessions user name (that they have logged in with) which is an email! I need to pass this to a separate page and output it in a table to represent a review submitted

$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name']; - sends page to login in when refreshed
$name = ['name'] - sends page back to login

```
<!-- logged in user information -->
<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) : ?>
<p>Welcome you are logged in as: <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></strong></p>
```

the 'email' needs passing across from the code above 'index.php' to the code below 'reviews.php'

```
<p>
<input name="product_id" value="<?php echo "$var" ?>" readonly> <!-- get value from previous page-->
<input name="track_name" value="<?php echo "$var_value" ?>" readonly> <!-- get value from previous page-->
<input name="track_name" value="<?php echo "EMAIL_HERE" ?>" readonly> <!-- get value from previous page-->
<!-- get value from previous page-->
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
```

As this is an assignment I can only use PHP MYSQL HTML CSS

I would like the user name (email) to be echo out in a table as $var and $var_value is, they should then all print out beside each other in a form

**UPDATE**
using this code I have managed to now get the variable value across but cannot insert it to the DB

`$email = $_SESSION['email'];`

`$sql = "INSERT INTO reviews (rating, review, track_name, product_id, email) values('$rate', '$text', '$track', '$artist', '$email')";`

``" readonly>```

so the update is how can I now get this inserted to my database?

Comment: I hope I asked and formatted this question correctly! TIA

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything; `$_SESSION` *automatically* persists across pages. Just reference the same `$_SESSION['email']` on the next page :)

Comment: was just about to comment if I use this ```<input name="track_name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?>" readonly>``` it stops me from submitting into my db

Comment: And don't forget to call `session_start()` in every script before you access `$_SESSION`

Comment: yes ```session_start();``` is called on all pages to ensure the user must be logged in

Answer (score -1, accepted):

FINALLY THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP ALL

`$email = $_SESSION['email'];` Get the email from session

`$email = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null);` Remove index error

`<input name="email" value="<?php echo "$email" ?>" readonly> <!-- get value from previous page-->` Display the value

`$review_query = mysqli_query($result,"SELECT rating, review, email FROM reviews WHERE track_name = '$var_value' AND product_id = '$var'");` Grab it from the DB

`<td class='col-4 col-s-4' name='email'><?php echo $email ?></td>` Output its value

Answer (score -1):

did you try to use $_SESSION['email'] variable in reviews.php page?
I hope that u are using CSRF tokens too

Comment: hi I have tried using ```$_SESSION['email']```. I am not that advanced on php sorry so I have not used tokens at all

Comment: as far as i know u must declare your page by require_once("PageName.php"); maybe that's why you are not able to pass variables through your pages.